# using select dropdown in angular material bottom sheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using bottom sheet in an application based on Angular material project(https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.bottomSheet). I have a form within the bottom sheet with a slider, input elements and a select dropdown. On desktop everything works fine but on a tablet or phone I can't seem to scroll through all the options in the dropdown. When I emulate the scroll on tablet/mobile the bottom sheet moves but not the dropdown. I have tried searching for a solution to this problem but have not found much help on the web.
Is there a way to disable swipe events on the bottom sheet or an alternative method to solve the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the scrolling issue with md-select in bottom sheet on tablet and phone view by using native select dropdown by utilizing hide-gt-md and hide-sm material css classes.

```
<md-bottom-sheet>
  <md-select hide-sm hide-md options...>
  </md-select>

  <select hide-gt-md options...>
  </select>
</md-bottom-sheet>
```